# C# EntityFramework Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I tried to implement a new function in one of my programs. This feature allows to add and edit project overviews. I'm using a One-To-Many Foreignkey in the database where a "Project" has one project leader (User) and one "User" has many project leads (Project). Now in the web API the code actually reaches the "return Ok(projectList);". But on the client it says internal server error.
I think it has something to do with the foreign key because the User class did already exist before I implemented the new feature. When I debug the API there aren't any errors and the propertys "ProjectLeader" and "ProjectLeads" are not null. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's the code:

User.cs

```
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
public string Username { get; set; }
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email format")]
public string EMail { get; set; }
[Required(AllowEmptryStrings = false)]
public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
public bool FirstLogin { get; set; }
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
public int ActivationCode { get; set; }
public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
public byte[] ProfilePicture { get; set; }
public UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Project> ProjectLeads { get; set; }
```

Project.cs

```
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required(AllowEmptryStrings = false)]
[ForeignKey("ProjectLeader_Id")]
public virtual User ProjectLeader { get; set; }
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
public string ProjectName { get; set; }
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
public string GameTitle { get; set; }
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
public string Description { get; set; }
public ProjectState ProjectState { get; set; }
public bool IsPC { get; set; }
public bool IsMac { get; set; }
public bool IsAndroid { get; set; }
public bool IsIOS { get; set; }
```

UserRole, UserGroup and ProjectState are enums.

The Method where I download the list of projects:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetProjects()
{
    var db = new DataBaseContext();

    try
    {
        if (db.Projects.Any())
        {
            var projectList = db.Projects.ToList();
            return Ok(projectList);
        }
        else
            return Ok(new List<Project>());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Fatal($"Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten beim Runterladen der Projekte: {ex.Message}", ex);
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten beim Runterladen der Projekte" means "An error occured while downloading the projects")

If it is important here's the DataBaseContext.cs:

```
public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<License> Licences { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

I searched through multiple tutorials on websites or in books I have at home. I did it exactly like they said. Am I missing something?

Comment: For your caught Exception: include the `Message`, the `Type`, the `StackTrace`, and repeat this recursivly across `InnerException`s all the way down. Use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44201949/edit) on your question to include that detail, do not include it as a comment. Based on your `log` statement you might be using log4net in which case all of this information should be readily available in your log file.

Comment: Disable CustomErrors and post the exception / stack trace.